# What is the recommended NLog release as of Aug 2018

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nlog

Hi there I need to upgrade some legacy software using NLog 2.1 to a later NLog release in order to leverage some of the new config functionality.  What is the most stable release out in the wild?

VS Version is 2013
.Net Version is 4.5

Comment: Always use the latest. NLog ver. 4.5.8 is good.

Comment: Thanks Rolf, already done, and working a treat... almost...  My legacy app uses a variable in nlog.config called 'logId'  which is then used within layout renders to include the logid as the first element in the log entry.  In the old app I used an XMLDoc instance to update the logid in the nlog.config file on disk, however its my understanding that I shouldn't need to do this, and that there are functions within Nlog itself which should allow me to persist the current logid to disk.  Is this correct or have I misunderstood this aspect of Nlog?  Your advice much appreciated.

Paul :-)

Comment: Not sure where the LogId comes from and when it is available. But you can use NLog Global Context to store global values at runtime. These can then be retrieved in the layout where needed. Ex. `${gdc:item=LogId}` See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer